# Is there a way to use create and return with cypher cases?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to create node n1 when rv exists and n2 in case not, I declared a variable flag if rv exists. I want to return n1 in case of flag true and n2 in case of false.

Hereby my code:

```
WITH rv IS NOT NULL AS flag
WHERE flag
CREATE (n1:Test1 {name: "Test1"})
Return n1

WITH flag
WHERE NOT flag
CREATE (n2:Test2 {name: "Test2"})
Return n2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an APOC function for this purpose.

```
Line 1 is an illustration when rv is null. Remove it on your actual query
Line 2 is using the APOC function 'do when'
Line 3 is the condition. if true then run line 4 else line 5
Line 4 is your true condition
Line 5 is your false condition
Line 6 returns the node that you created

1    WITH null as rv
2    CALL apoc.do.when(
3      rv is not null,
4      "CREATE (n1:Test1 {name: 'Test1'}) RETURN n1",
5      "CREATE (n2:Test2 {name: 'Test2'}) RETURN n2") YIELD value 
6    RETURN value
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using [apoc.do.when](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.2/overview/apoc.do/apoc.do.when/), as suggested by @jose_bacoy, you can use [apoc.create.node](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.2/overview/apoc.create/apoc.create.node/):

```
... // prior Cypher that defines rv
WITH CASE
  WHEN rv IS NULL THEN {l: 'Test2', n: 'Test2'}
  ELSE {l: 'Test1', n: 'Test1'}
END AS x
CALL apoc.create.node([x.l], {name: x.n}) YIELD node AS n
RETURN n
```

Or, if you want to avoid using the APOC library for some reason, you can use a [CALL subquery](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/5/clauses/call-subquery/) in neo4j 4.1+:

```
... // prior Cypher that defines rv
CALL {
    WITH rv
    WITH rv WHERE rv IS NOT NULL
    CREATE (n:Test1 {name: "Test1"})
    RETURN n

    UNION

    WITH rv
    WITH rv WHERE rv IS NULL
    CREATE (n:Test2 {name: 'Test2'})
    RETURN n
}
RETURN n
```